# Cannot insert data from PHP into MYSQL server from a Registration Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I've been trying to get a set of code to work, and currently am unsure about where to go next. I have the HTML, the JS and the PHP setup, but I am unsure where the error lies. When I submit the form, the form resets, and none of the data that I want sent to the SQL is being sent to database. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

The form I have for HTML

```
        <form  id="SignUp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="registration.php">
  <div class="container2">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>

    <label ><b>First Name</b></label>  <label id="name1_msg" class="err_msg"></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="name1" required> <br/>

    <label ><b>Last Name</b></label>  <label id="name2_msg" class="err_msg"></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="name2" required> <br/>

    <label ><b>Email</b></label>  <label id="email_msg" class="err_msg"></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required><br/>

    <label ><b>Date of Birth</b></label>  <label id="DOB_msg" class="err_msg"></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Date of Birth DD-MM-YYYY" name="DOB" required><br/>

    <label ><b>Password</b></label>  <label id="pswd_msg" class="err_msg"></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pswd" required><br/>

    <label ><b>Repeat Password</b></label>  <label id="pswdr_msg" class="err_msg"></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="pswdr" required><br/>

    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
    <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">

    <hr>

    <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms + Privacy</a>.</p>
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Sign up" name="submit" /> <label id="s_msg" class="err_msg"></label>
    <p>Already have an account? <a href="main.php">Sign in</a>.</p>
  </div>

</form>
```

I have JS verifying all of the inputs, which then follows with the PHP code, which also verifies it, but server side, which SHOULD then insert all of the information above into the SQL database.

```
    <?php
    $validate = true;
    $name1 = trim($_POST["name1"]);
    $name2 = trim($_POST["name2"]);
    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $DOB = trim($_POST["DOB"]);
    $pswd = trim($_POST["pswd"]);
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "myDB");
    if ($db->connect_error)
    {
        die ("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
    }

    $q1 = "SELECT * FROM ShopUser WHERE email = '$email'";
    $r1 = $db->query($q1);

    if($r1->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $validate = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $name1Match = preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z_-]+$/", $name1);
        if($name1 == null || $name1 == "" || $name1Match == false)
        {
            $validate = false;
        }

        $name2Match = preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z_-]+$/", $name2);
        if($name2 == null || $name2 == "" || $name2Match == false)
        {
            $validate = false;
        }

        $emailMatch = preg_match("/^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/", $email);
        if($email == null || $email == "" || $emailMatch == false)
        {
            $validate = false;
        }

        $DOBMatch = preg_match("/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\- \/.](?:(0[1-9]|1[012])[\- \/.](19|20)[0-9]{2})$/", $DOB);
        if($DOB == null || $DOB == "" || $DOBMatch == false)
        {
            $validate = false;
        }

        $pswdLen = strlen($pswd);
        $pswdMatch = preg_match("/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$/", $pswd);
        if($pswd == null || $pswd == "" || $pswdLen< 8 || $pswdMatch == false)
        {
            $validate = false;
        }

        $target_dir = "pictures/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . ShopUser($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

        if($check == false || $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 2000000 || 
$imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
            && $imageFileType != "gif")
        {
            $validate = false;
        }

    }

    if($validate == true)
    {
        $dateFormat = date("DD-MM-YYYY", strtotime($DOB));

        $q2 = "INSERT INTO ShopUser (name1, name2, email, DOB, pswd)
                VALUES ('$name1', '$name2', '$email', '$dateFormat', '$pswd')";


        $r2 = $db->query($q2);
        if ($r2 === true)
        {
            header("Location: main.php");
            $db->close();
            exit();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "alert('Error! Something has gone wrong, please try again')";
        $db->close();
    }}?>
```

Comment: Hey, Throw your query in a prepared statement for security. Also PDO is so much better than mysqli. Just saying.

Comment: Where is your code going wrong at? Use echo statements to find out how far your code is making it. Like after each of statement.

Comment: Where should I put the echo statements? I know that the form is completing, and that the Javascript is running, however it's a problem with the form information not being passed into the SQL.

Comment: echo statement to see if $validate is true when it gets to the bottom so put one right above the $dateformat Also surround your database insert with a try catch to see if it spits something back out

Comment: also echo out all the post variables to make sure they are correct. again you can echo them out at the end. Just make sure they all show up. All 5 of them

Comment: Give me a few minutes I am rewriting this. Its failing at line 19

Comment: Hey whats this line supposed to do:         $target_file = $target_dir . ShopUser($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]); BEcause by calling ShopUSer the way your doing it you are calling a function. Do you have a function written for shopuser or is this a mistake.If so what is the purpose of that line.

Comment: ShopUser is meant to be the database table

Comment: When you say the database table. What do you mean? you cant call the database table like that. Are you trying to include the word ShopUser in your path. You never declare shopUser before that, that's whats throwing me off.

Comment: OK Also after the if statement on line 21 . the one where your checking the number of rows, you are going into a dead end as nothing else will validate if that's false. With that $target_file statement what are you trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Well this is what I have thus far. Here is the, I included error handling at the top of the code so from this point on you can see the error or warning and let me know what your getting and I can help you fix it. However I cannot run the full code as I do not have the function ShopUser that you are calling

```
<?php
//This Will Report Errors and Warnings
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$validate = true;
$name1 = trim($_POST["name1"]);
$name2 = trim($_POST["name2"]);
$email = trim($_POST["email"]);
$DOB = trim($_POST["DOB"]);
$pswd = trim($_POST["pswd"]);
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "myDB");
    if ($db->connect_error) {
        die ("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
    }

    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ShopUser WHERE email= ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($num);
    $stmt->fetch();

    if ($num > 0) {
        echo('User Already Exists');
        $validate = false;
    } else {
        echo $validate;

        $name1Match = preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z_-]+$/", $name1);
        if ($name1 == null || $name1 == "" || $name1Match == false) {
            $validate = false;
        }

        $name2Match = preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z_-]+$/", $name2);
        if ($name2 == null || $name2 == "" || $name2Match == false) {
            $validate = false;
        }

        $emailMatch = preg_match("/^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/", $email);
        if ($email == null || $email == "" || $emailMatch == false) {
            $validate = false;
        }

        $DOBMatch = preg_match("/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\- \/.](?:(0[1-9]|1[012])[\- \/.](19|20)[0-9]{2})$/", $DOB);
        if ($DOB == null || $DOB == "" || $DOBMatch == false) {
            $validate = false;
        }

        $pswdLen = strlen($pswd);
        $pswdMatch = preg_match("/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$/", $pswd);
        if ($pswd == null || $pswd == "" || $pswdLen < 8 || $pswdMatch == false) {
            $validate = false;
        }

        $target_dir = "pictures/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . ShopUser($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

        if ($check == false || $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 2000000 ||
            $imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
            && $imageFileType != "gif") {
            $validate = false;
        }

    }

    if ($validate == true) {
        $dateFormat = date("DD-MM-YYYY", strtotime($DOB));

        try {
            $q2 = "INSERT INTO ShopUser (name1, name2, email, DOB, pswd)
                VALUES ('$name1', '$name2', '$email', '$dateFormat', '$pswd')";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e . 'not Working';
        }


        $r2 = $db->query($q2);
        if ($r2 === true) {
            header("Location: main.php");
            $db->close();
            exit();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "alert('Error! Something has gone wrong, please try again')";
        $db->close();
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help friend, I'll get to work on fixing it, and if I do I'll let you know. Thank you, thank you.

Comment: Hey I just updated this all to work with your database again. I accidentally kept my local testing DB variables in the code. Its fixed now though. However this is still not going to work but I want to know what error you get now

Comment: No problem. But the way I added your DB connection now is through a prepared statement. From now on thats what you should use to access your DB, it prevents SQL injections